# Como devolver un codigo 400 personalizado en una api rest express js

Tags: nodejs, express, rest

Hola soy nuevo en express, estoy validando mi api, y cuando digito una ruta distinta a la que tengo en la api
(correcto: `api/v1/unidades` / incorrecto: `api/v1/unidaaaades`) me devuelve un html de error y me gustaria enviar un simple texto como 'No se encontro el recurso solicitado' con el codigo 400. Solo se me ocurre enviar un codigo de respuesta 500 desde el controlador cuando hay problemas en la transaccion a la BBDD, pero no se como y de donde enviar el codigo 400 (si desde el index del proyecto o desde el controlador o enrutador) cuando el usuario solicita un recurso que no tengo. Aqui mi codigo.

controladorConductor.js

```
const obtenerTodos = async (req, res) => {
    const { Pool } = require('pg')
    const connection = require('../conexion')
    const pool = new Pool(connection.postgresql)

    
    const text = 'SELECT * FROM "Conductor"'
    try {
        const r = await pool.query(text)
        res.json(r.rows)
        await pool.end()
    } catch (error) {
        // como enviaria un 400? de recurso no encontrado
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
}
```

enrutadorConductor.js

```
const express = require('express')
const conductorControlador = require('../controladores/conductor')
const conductorEnrutador = express.Router()

conductorEnrutador.get('/conductores', conductorControlador.obtenerTodos)
```

el index del API

```
const express = require('express')
const conductorEnrutador = require('./rutas/conductor')
const app = express()

app.use()

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(conductorEnrutador)
app.set('titulo', 'Carvi API')
app.set('puerto', 4500)
app.listen(app.get('puerto'), () => {
    console.log('Corriendo aplicacion en el puerto: ' + app.get('puerto'))
})
```

PD. Solo estoy pegando el codigo necesario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quiero aclarar que esto debe ir DESPUES de todas tus rutas, se ejecutaria si haces una peticion a una URL que no existe.

```
app.use() // Esto no tiene sentido
--------->
app.use('*', (req, res) => res.status(404).send("Parece que te has perdido");
```

Lo mejor es pescificar que ruta estas usando en tu API

```
const conductorEnrutador = require('./rutas/conductor')
app.use('/api', conductorEnrutador)
app.use('*', (req, res) => res.status(404).send("Parece que te has perdido"));
```

Puedes enviar un error 404 de tu controlador pero no te recomendaria hacer eso, tiene que ver mucho sobre los estados de HTTP, 404 indica que EL RECURSO SOLICITADO NO EXISTE, te recomiendo usar un codigo 204, que indica que no hay resultados. Los codigos 200-2xx son de solicitudes completadas satisfactoriamente, un error 400-4xx representa un problema entre el cliente al servidor.

> 204 No Content (en-US) La petición se ha completado con éxito pero su
> respuesta no tiene ningún contenido

```
   try {
        const r = await pool.query(text)
        res.json(r.rows)
        await pool.end()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({error: "No hay ningun recurso disponible"});
        //res.sendStatus(204)
    }
```

En el frontend, donde provenga tu REQUEST/SOLICITUD, un error 404 ocaciona generalmente un ERROR, asi que si tuvieras un problema/o no hubiera resultados, tendrias un error, en cambio, un estado 204 te diria directamente que no hay resultados disponibles.

```
request("tu/super/url")
.then(res => res.status === 204 ? "No hay resultados en tu busqueda" : res.data)
.catch(e => console.log("error:", e.message))
```

Comment: Estados HTTP para respuestas diversas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Answer (score 0):

Encontre esto en la documentacion de express
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses

En Express, las respuestas 404 no son el resultado de un error, por lo que el middleware del controlador de errores no las capturará. Este comportamiento se debe a que una respuesta 404 simplemente indica la ausencia de trabajo adicional por hacer; en otras palabras, Express ha ejecutado todas las funciones y rutas de middleware y descubrió que ninguna de ellas respondió. Todo lo que necesita hacer es agregar una función de middleware en la parte inferior de la pila (debajo de todas las demás funciones) para manejar una respuesta 404:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```